# Configure Keycloak for time difference between it and AD server (SAML)

Tags: keycloak

I don't have control over the AD authentication server which provides SAML assertions. The AD server's time is often off by a few seconds.

From Keycloak's logs:

```
16:08:33,713 DEBUG [org.keycloak.saml.validators.ConditionsValidator] (default task-5) Evaluating Conditions of Assertion _1468eee4-406b-4fd8-8743-b60c5df535b6. notBefore=2019-07-02T20:08:37.322Z, notOnOrAfter=2019-07-02T21:08:37.322Z
```

Note that the AD notBefore time is 4 seconds after Keycloak's log time.

Is there a Keycloak setting to provide an acceptable time drift?

Comment: AD notBefore is 4 seconds and AD off by few seconds.. The AD admin should actually take a look at it :S

Answer (score 2):

Keycloak is [adding a feature](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-8104) to allow for clock skew (it's just about [there](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/6050)). It's unclear from your problem statement whether this Keycloak change would completely address your case but give it a shot.